# TinyMCE editor how to select with cursor custom HTML element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor where I have inserted a custom HTML (Placeholder). How can I select with cursor this element like a normal text? It needs to be selected to apply Bold, Italic, and Underline format.

Probably 'contenteditable="false"' is the problem, but if I set it on true, I can modify the text of this, and is not allowed. The "Placeholder" element needs to remain static and unchangeable.

```
<span contenteditable="false" class="placeholderClass" data-mce-selected="1">Placeholder<i id="removePlaceholder"></i> </span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short and sad answer is that what you ask is not possible with TinyMCE. An element is either non-editable and non-formattable, or editable *and* formattable.